# Interfaces with set methods only for initialization?

Tags: c#, methods, interface

I am trying to change all arguments to interfaces instead of class instances.
However, when I try this, I have the problem that I need to add a lot of set methods to interfaces, which I rather only want get methods in. The reason is that methods are used for initialization and need set methods only once during initalization.

Example:

```
 protected IPcgMemory CurrentPcgMemory { get; private set; }

 protected PatchesFileReader(IPcgMemory currentPcgMemory, byte[] content)
 {
     CurrentPcgMemory = currentPcgMemory;
     CurrentPcgMemory.Content = content;
 }
```

Error: IMemory.Content has no setter (in last line)

```
public interface IPcgMemory : IMemory, INavigable
    ...

public interface IMemory : ...
    byte[] Content { get; }
```

I only want the get method in the interface of IMemory for Content, but not the set method. 
Should I remove the interface and use the instance for currentPcgMemory like:

```
 protected PatchesFileReader(PcgMemory currentPcgMemory, byte[] content)
```

Or should I make the set available in Content like:

```
public interface IMemory : ...
    byte[] Content { get; set; }
```

Or is there a better solution?

Comment: one alternative is for your interface to provide a `Setup(IPcgMemory CurrentPcgMemory)` method instead of the property setter as this is more explicit in its intended purpose

Comment: why do you need to assign `Content` in the `PatchesFileReader` constructor? I'm thinking you could just accept an `IPcgMemory` instance and allow callers to construct the concrete instance appropriately.

Comment: Well, I rather have the set method only being called by the constructor itself, so I can be sure it will never be possible to set from outside.

Comment: But the caller will still be able to pass that reference to whoever he wants, and they can modify from outside. You wouldn't, by chance, come from a C++ background?

Comment: Yes (but that's long ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialization of the instance which implements the interface is part of the public "interface". An interface with a property that only has a getter means that setting is *never* possible.

There's no concept of an interface for only what's most often done.

On the other hand, if you had a situation where you want to pass a reference to one layer, where the instance can be initialized, and then that layer passes the reference to other layers, which can only read it, then you can use two interfaces:

```
public interface IReadable {
    int SomeProperty {get;}
}

public interface IInitializable : IReadable {
    int SomeProperty {get;set;}
}

IReadable _passItOn;
public void InitializeAndUse(IInitializable initAndUse){
    _passItOn = initAndUse;
    initAndUse.SomeProperty = 42;

    UseReadOnly(_passItOn);
}
```

Comment: The (private) setter can be called from the constructor or do I miss something?

Comment: That looks like a good idea ... possibly I will use the InitializeAndUse code directly from the constructor, but the idea is the same. Thanks!